# Required in what time cistern would be filled by the second pipe alone. Task from the Elements of Algebra by L. Euler

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A certain cistern, which  would be filled in 12minutes  by two pipes  running into it, would be filled  in 20 minutes by one alone.  Required in what time it would be filled by the other alone.

My guess is that I have to come up with some equation system, but I just can't figure out the right equation. And I'm not even sure if I'n on the right path to solve this task.

Comment: Can you do it if you assume the tank holds $1200$ gallons?

Comment: I see. It was even easier than I thought. l/20 + l/x = l/12 => x = 30. I don't know what happened to my brain... Thanks, anyway!